# Proof heading moved when combining mdframed, amsmath and amsthm

Tags: amsmath, mdframed, amsthm

I have a document in which I declare a `thm` environment using `amsthm`, and then I decorate these theorem using `\surroundwithmdframed` from `mdframed` package. In addition, I have the `amsmath` for other purposes.

In my theorems, I include the proof using the standard `proof` environment (from `amsthm`). This proof environment begins the proof with a "Proof. " heading and closes with a square (`\qed`).

I this context, when I write a theorem starting with a math environment (`\[...\]`), the proof heading (i.e. "Proof. ") is not printed. Even more surprising, the "Proof. " heading is *moved* at the begining of the following (non-thm) environment.

For instance, in the following example, the proof of Theorem 1 should read "*Proof.* Trivial. `\qed`". However, the "*Proof. *" is moved just before the "Centered." after.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\mdfdefinestyle{thm-frame}{}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=thm-frame]{thm}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
    \[\forall P\cdot P\]
    \begin{proof}
            Trivial.
    \end{proof}
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}

\end{thm}
\begin{center}
    Centered.
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Notice that:

- if any of the 3 packages is removed (and the file is modified accordingly, e.g. by removing the `\surroundwithmdframed`), the problem does not occur anymore
- if the theorem does *not* begin with a `\[ ... \]` math environment (e.g. a `\(...\)` math environment or a sentence), the problem does not occur
- this is, by far, the strangest behavior of LaTeX I encountered so far...

Comment: Why do you have the `proof` inside the `thm`, they are two separate things.

Comment: I would suggest *not* to nest a proof environment within a thm environment, and simply use an outer `mdframed` environment which encloses both the theorem and its proof.

Comment: The reason proofs are nested in theorem is mainly historical. I don't have a strong opinion on this, but the original reason is that I was told, more or less, that theorems are nothing without their proof, hence proof should go with their theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to drop mdframed. It has bugs and is no longer maintained. Use tcolorbox instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,breakable}

\tcolorboxenvironment{thm}{
enhanced jigsaw,colframe=cyan,interior hidden,
breakable,before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt }


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}{}
    \[\forall P\cdot P\]
    \begin{proof}
            Trivial.
    \end{proof}

\end{thm}
\begin{thm}

\end{thm}
\begin{center}
    Centered.
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I'll apply the change before accepting the answer ;-)